# How to handle duplicated HTML checkbox list in Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, facet

I have a list of checkboxes on a sidebar, used for a facetted navigation, this sidebar is hidden when the width of the screen is small, it's a responsive design, then there is a button to make the offcanvas sidebar (which is exactly the same) appear.
My current code is like that, the facets are the different weights :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<li ng-repeat="attr in layout.facettes.weight">
  <input id="facet1" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" ng-selected="{{attr.isSelected}}">
  <label for="facet1" class="checkbox-custom-label">
    {{attr.Label}}
  </label>
</li>
```

Label is the label of the facet : 10kg, 20kg, 30 kg etc.
 the facet object is like :

```
facettes {
    weight  : [{"Label" : "10kg",IsSelected : false },{...}],
    length : [{...},{...}]
}
```

The html code of the sidebar is included through RenderPartial two times in the layout.cshtml, one for small screen view, one for the other sizes..

with label for="" there is a problem to make the second instance of the sidebar work, well. So i tried to use angular ng-select to handle the checkboxes.
Problem : I can only click on the first checkbox, the second one refuses to work.
I think duplicating html code is not good but hwo to achieve the same result then? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: I tried to use $index, works ok for the first sidebar but not the second

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but here is the code from what I understand so far

```
    <li ng-repeat="attr in layout.facettes.weight">
        <input id="facet{{$index}}" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" ng-checked="attr.IsSelected">
        <label for="facet{{$index}}" class="checkbox-custom-label">
            {{attr.Label}}
        </label>
    </li>
        <li ng-repeat="attr in layout.facettes.weight">
        <input id="facet2{{$index}}" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{attr.IsSelected}}">
        <label for="facet2{{$index}}" class="checkbox-custom-label">
            {{attr.Label}}
        </label>
    </li>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/22359/)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is two way binding in Angular, I can make the duplicated HTML elements to have the same value than the original HTML, and vice et versa.
The reason the ckecbox didn't work on the duplicated HTML checkbox was the for atribute of the label element.
Only the first checkbox was involved.
SO I removed he for attribute in the label element, and thanks to Angular binding, their states are kept in sync.

```
                <li ng-repeat="valueAttr in attr.Values">
                <div ng-click="valueAttr.IsSelected = !valueAttr.IsSelected">
                    <input class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" ng-checked="valueAttr.IsSelected">
                    <label class="checkbox-custom-label">
                        {{valueAttr.Label}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
```

It is very important to keep in mind that Angular takes care of syncing between the view and the model, without that mechanism the solution would not be so simple.